# How to use dotnet monitor in windows containers to collect application metrics

Tags: .net, azure, kubernetes, .net-core, monitor

I'm trying to set up the use of dotnet-monitor in a windows pod. But if I understand correctly, there are no images for use on Windows nodes https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-monitor. Is there any way to install dotnet-monitor utilities in Dockerfile windows pod to start collecting metrics from my windows application?

Comment: This might not currently be supported. There's an open issue about this https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/issues/1160, but it doesn't have much detail.

Comment: perhaps I can install separately using the command
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-monitor --version 6.0.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

The side car approach for setting up Dotnet Monitor in a Windows Container to get the diagnostics logs of a different container is currently not supported as mentioned by ***Jander-MSFT*** in this ***[`Github Issue`](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/issues/1160)*** which might get resolved by this ***[`Issue`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63950).***

***As a Solution , You will have to install the tool on the same Windows container by running the below command :***

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-monitor --version 6.0.0
```

You can refer this ***[`blog`](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/exploring-your-net-applications-with-dotnetmonitor)*** by ***Scott Hanselman*** for more details on the same .